# How to keep in Yii always the same URL after switching between actions?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I want to do that: I have my domain http://www.domain.com, the login is public so no password is needed, just put your team name and select the sport, so in the login page you type team1 and basket, you login with that credential and you see the information related.

But the customer wants to show allways the same url like this: http://www.domain.com/team1/basket, http://www.domain.com/team1/baseball, http://www.domain.com/team3/hockey and so forth, only when click logout is going to appear http://www.domain.com. But if the user press the button to go to the controller 'site' method 'actionScore', the page will enter en /site/score, but the url it should be still http://www.domain.com/team1/baseball, but if the user types the url http://www.domain.com/team1/basket is going to change to this one and relogin with that credentials.

I don't know if it is possible to do this in yii, maybe the only way to do it is in htaccess, but then again I do not know how to set the htaccess to perform that behaviour.

Comment: you can make a angular application, with a RESTful server by yii, for this to be clean

Answer (score 0):

## 1 solution: make everything on ajax.

`CHtml::ajaxLink()` will help you a lot.

## 2 solution (simple, but not pretty): Use history api:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

```
jQuery(function() {
    history.replaceState('http://domain.com');
}
```

Comment: I could use solution 1, with Ajax, everything in the same action 'site/index'(it is a small website). But my doubt is how Do I do to make team1/baseball, team2/hockey... points always to site/index.